# How to get spark SUBMISSION_ID with spark-submit?

Tags: apache-spark

Many places need `SUBMISSION_ID`, like [`spark-submit --status`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37420931/5634636) and Spark REST API. But how can I get this `SUBMISSION_ID` when I use `spark-submit` command to submit spark jobs?

P.S.:

I use python `[popen][2]` to start a `spark-submit` job. I want `SUBMISSION_ID` so my python program can monitor spark job status via REST API: `<ip>:6066/v1/submissions/status/<SUBMISSION_ID>`

Comment: Please have a look at this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29990153/submit-kill-spark-application-program-programmatically-from-another-applicatio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the clue by @Pandey. The answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/37980813/5634636 helps me a lot.

### TL;DR

- If you want to submit spark job locally, the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/37980813/5634636 indeed works.
  The only point is you must use **`cluster`** mode to submit your job,
  i.e., use parameter `--deploy-mode cluster`.
- If you want to submit a spark job remotely, use Spark submission API. It will help a lot. See https://www.nitendragautam.com/spark/submit-apache-spark-job-with-rest-api/ for details.

### Detailed description

> NOTE: I only test my approaches on Apache Spark 2.3.1. I can't guarantee that it will work in other versions as well.

Let's clear my requirement first. There're 3 features I wanted:

1. remote submit a spark job
2. check job status anytime (RUNNING, ERROR, FINISHED...)
3. get the error message if there is something error

#### Submit locally

> NOTE: this answer only works in ***cluster*** mode

The Spark tool `spark-submit` will help.

- To submit a job, see
  https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/submitting-applications.html#launching-applications-with-spark-submit
- To check the status, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/37420931/5634636. In this way, you need a `SubmissionID`. This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/37980813/5634636 told you how to get a submission id **in cluster mode**. The submission id looks like `driver-20190315142356-0004`.
- The error message is included in the job status message.

#### Submit remotely

Spark submission API is recommended. It seems that there is not any documentation on Apache Spark official website, so some people call it *hidden API*. For details, see: https://www.nitendragautam.com/spark/submit-apache-spark-job-with-rest-api/

- To submit Spark job, use submit API
- To get the status of the job, use status API: `http://<master-ip>:6066/v1/submissions/status/<submission-id>`. The `submission-id` will be returned in a json when you submit jobs.
- The error message is included in the status message.
- More about the error message: note the difference between status **ERROR** and **FAILED**. In short, the FAILED means that there is something wrong during executing *Spark jobs* (e.g. uncaught exceptions), while the ERROR means there's something error during *submitting* (e.g. invalid jar path). The error message is included in the status json. If you want to view the FAILED reason, it can be accessed via `http://<driver-ip>:<ui-port>/log/<submission-id>`.

Here is an example of error status (**** is an incorrect jar path which is miswritten intentionally):

```
{
  "action" : "SubmissionStatusResponse",
  "driverState" : "ERROR",
  "message" : "Exception from the cluster:\njava.io.FileNotFoundException: File hdfs:**** does not exist.\n\torg.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.listStatusInternal(DistributedFileSystem.java:795)\n\torg.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.access$700(DistributedFileSystem.java:106)\n\torg.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$18.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:853)\n\torg.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$18.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:849)\n\torg.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)\n\torg.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.listStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:860)\n\torg.apache.spark.util.Utils$.fetchHcfsFile(Utils.scala:727)\n\torg.apache.spark.util.Utils$.doFetchFile(Utils.scala:695)\n\torg.apache.spark.util.Utils$.fetchFile(Utils.scala:488)\n\torg.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverRunner.downloadUserJar(DriverRunner.scala:155)\n\torg.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverRunner.prepareAndRunDriver(DriverRunner.scala:173)\n\torg.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverRunner$$anon$1.run(DriverRunner.scala:92)",
  "serverSparkVersion" : "2.3.1",
  "submissionId" : "driver-20190315160943-0005",
  "success" : true,
  "workerHostPort" : "172.18.0.4:36962",
  "workerId" : "worker-20190306214522-172.18.0.4-36962"
}
```